# How to increment a variable each time through a loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, foreach

I'm writing a macro that takes a list of numbers as its only parameter.  When I iterate through the list, I'd like to keep track of the index of the item in the list.  Here's an example of what I want:

```
% \myMacro{2,1,3} \\ % this is the same as what follows

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1,0) -- +(0,2);
  \draw (2,0) -- +(0,1);
  \draw (3,0) -- +(0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Pretending that `\index` is the way to get what I want, I'd write this macro as:

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \height in #1 {
      \draw (\index,0) -- +(0,\height);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}}
```

Is there a way to do this?  I know that, if I wanted to call it as `\myMacro{2/1,1/2,3/3}`, I could replace one line with `\foreach \height/\index in #1 {`, but I'd much prefer to not need to pass the indicies in the parameter.

Comment: For future, please don't post code fragments, but instead put the fragment into a minimal compilable document (even if it gives an error) like I did in my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `pgffor`  package (part of `tikz`) provides a `count` key for this which you can assign to a macro. Note that you need `{  }` around the `#1` in your macro definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \height [count=\myindex] in {#1} {
      \draw (\myindex,0) -- +(0,\height);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}  
\mymacro{2,1,3}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]